# ¿Cómo resetear variables en cada ejecución del script con python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Me ocurre muchas veces que cada vez que ejecuto un script de python el valor de las variables de la ejecución anterior queda en la memoria y eso me provoca errores y confusiones en la siguiente ejecución del srcript si he hecho modificaciones. Sinceramente es bastante molesto... ¿Existe alguna forma de decirle a python que vacie la memoria cuando acabe cada ejecución?

---

### --------------------------------ACTUALIZACION-------------------------------

El último error que tuve fue con este código

## Fusionar dos playlist con el mismo nombre

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

 flags = argparser.parse_args()
 client_read_write = credentials_lib.get_authenticated_service(flags) 
 
 playlist = YouTubeData()
 playlist = playlist_lib.search_playlists("xxxxxxxxxxxx")
 
 pl = YouTubeData() 
 
 for i in range( len(playlist.id) ):
  #print("Playlist encontrada=%s (%s)" % (playlist.id[i], playlist.title[i]))
  if  comprueba_si_esta_en_lista(pl.title, playlist.title[i]) == False:
   pl.title.append(playlist.title[i])
   pl.id.append(playlist.id[i])
  else:       
   for j in range( len(pl.id) ):
    if playlist.title[i] == pl.title[j] and playlist.id[i] != pl.id[j]:
     print("Playlist repetida1=%s (%s)" % (playlist.id[i], playlist.title[i]))
     print("Playlist repetida2=%s (%s)" % (pl.id[j], pl.title[j]))
     video = playlist_lib.get_playlistItems(playlist.id[i])
     for k in range( len(video.id) ):
      playlist_lib.add_video_to_playlist(client_read_write, pl.id[j], video.id[k], pl.title[j])
     playlist_lib.playlist_delete(client_read_write, playlist.id[i])
```

En la primera ejecución borré las playlist, luego volvía ejecutar el script para ver si habia funcionado bien y me salió este error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ivan\Desktop\Codigos_YouTube\9-buscar\merge_playlist.py", line 39, in <module>
    video = playlist_lib.get_playlistItems(playlist.id[i])
  File "C:\Users\ivan\Desktop\Codigos_YouTube\9-buscar\playlist_lib.py", line 44, in get_playlistItems
    res = req.execute()
  File "C:\Users\ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ivan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 840, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?playlistId=PLDKzQrO-MACfjGE060F5D7u5u5OCsmkKh&part=snippet&maxResults=50&key=AIzaSy
BvxPKzriIEu2srReQdy-MepNVI367kku4&alt=json returned "The playlist identified with the requests <code>playlistId</code> parameter cannot be found.">
```

Basicámente me dice que le estoy dando el ID de una playlist que no existe y es lógico porque ya la habia borrado.

La conclusión a la que llego es que la variable **playlist.id[i]** quedo en la memoria de la ejecución anterior. Y cosas así me ocurren continuamente.

Comment: Iván  lo que comentas usando el intérprete Python normal es imposible que ocurra. ¿Usas algún ide?¿Cómo ejecutas los scripts?

Comment: los ejecuto así desde la consola (CMD) de windows **py -3 myscript.py**

Comment: Será cosa del API de de YouTube?... Habia borrado una lista de reproducción y en la siguiente ejecución volvió a usar el valor de una variable que no deberia existir (pues ya lo habia borrado)... ¿Te pongo el código?

Comment: @FJSevilla, he puesto el código y el error que me dá ahí arriba... a lo mejor tu le encuentras otra explicación.

Comment: Iván por parte del intérprete Python lo puedes descartar, eso es sencillamente imposible, cada vez que ejecutas el intérprete se crea un nuevo proceso y la memoria de la ejecución anterior fue liberada y el SO puede hacer lo que crea conveniente con ella, no cabe posibilidad alguna que valores de variables de ejecuciones anteriores influyan en algo. Además el objeto `playlist` y por tanto `playlist.id[i]`  es definido aquí `playlist = playlist_lib.search_playlists("xxxxxxxxxxxx")` por lo que aparentemente `playlist_lib.search_playlists` te está retornando una lista que no existe en realidad,

Comment: Entonces debe ser culpa del servidor de YouTube...seguro que debe tardar un tiempo en actualizar su base de datos o algo así...Me tiene loco!! :-) Gracias @FjSevilla